# Django REST How to filter through a slash?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using Django REST on the API. My Models:

```
class Region(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='child', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Ad(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30 , help_text='Title ads' , db_column='data')
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,help_text='Date Create')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    region = TreeForeignKey(Region,blank=True , null=True, related_name='Reg',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = TreeForeignKey(Category,blank=True , null=True, related_name='ad',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    views = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My serializers:

```
class AdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'region', 'category','price' , 'date_create','id','views','images')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ad = AdSerializer(many=True)
    child = RecursiveField(allow_null=True,required=False,many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name','id','ad','child')

class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = RecursiveField(allow_null=True, required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ('name','id' , 'children')
```

views.py :

```
class AdViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ad.objects.all().order_by('-date_create')
    serializer_class = AdSerializer
```

how do I now write urls.py, views.py, so I can filter through the slash by region and by category? For example http://localhost:8000/{region}/{category}/.
I will be happy for any advice and sorry for in my English

Comment: Is it possible to implement it using nested router ?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: @Umair can not show a small example?

Comment: Posted as an answer sir, maybe you'll need to tweak it as per you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we achieve that with something like this :

A base router for Ad, then a nested router for region, hopefully you can do same thing for category also. ViewSets for corresponding, please investigate and use lookup carefully, as per your situation.

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'ad', AdViewSet, base_name='ad')
ads_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'ads', lookup='ad')
ads_router.register(r'region', AdRegionViewSet, base_name='ad-region')


class AdRegionViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AdRegionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Region.objects.filter(id__in=Ad.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['ad_pk']))


class AdViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AdSerializer
    queryset = Ad.objects.all()
```

***Credit and Reference : https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers***

Comment: Hello @Umair! I want to register via phone number and use this phone number as login. How can I do this with something you can not advise? I looked at some libraries, but there was no example and could not implement.

Comment: Does solution mentioned above worked ? If yes then https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
and for this follow-up query, can open another question ?